# with jeet, how do i keep my columns ratio when using gutters

Tags: css, stylus, jeet-grid

I am trying to have four columns in jeet with a gutter of .5

```
col(1/4, gutter: .5, cycle: 1/4)
```

This causes the fourth column to break, giving me only 3.
I tried it without a gutter and the same thing happens.

```
col(1/4, cycle: 1/4)
```

Answer (score 0):

The cycle value essentially needs to be the number of columns... i.e. at which element do you want the row to end...

So your example would become

```
col(1/4, gutter: .5, cycle: 4)
```

Hope this helps!